# How to customize color in multiBarAndStack chart of NVD3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, nvd3.js

I want to change the default color of multiBarAndStack. i try to use this code but there is no change please someone help me, this is the code that i used:

```
d3.selectAll("nv-bar positive")
        .style("fill", function(d, i){
            return d.y > 50 ? "red":"blue";
        });
```

Comment: try this: `var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart(); chart.color(['red', 'blue']);`

Comment: What is multiBarAndStack? I don't see it in [the examples](http://nvd3.org/examples/) or in [the source](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/tree/master/src/models).